# ODBC_connect runs only with psql user

Tags: php, odbc, unixodbc

I have a php script who ask data from a odbc database (pervasive client).

When i run the script in CLI as the psql user (which the installer created) , then i have no problems and the script runs.

When i run the script in browser ( as www-data) or in CLI as root  or as a cronjob then i receive the error :

```
PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect in /var/ww....
```

i have added the user www-data & root in the groups that the pervasive client has installed.

Everything runs on a Debian server.

Comment: Is PHP 32-bit or 64-bit? What is output of `ls -l /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so` and `file /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so`?

Comment: i run the 64 bit version , the output of the ls command is :     `lrwxrwxrwx 1 psql pvsw 15 jun  5 15:52 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so -> libodbcci.so.11`.  The output of the file command is :     `/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so: symbolic link to libodbcci.so.11`

Comment: the output of the ls command is : `lrwxrwxrwx 1 psql pvsw 15 jun 5 15:52 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so -> libodbcci.so.11`. The output of the file command is : `/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so: symbolic link to libodbcci.so.11`

Comment: So now the obvious... what is output of `ls -l /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11` and `file /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11`

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 psql pvsw 26 jun  5 15:52 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11 -> libodbcci.so.11.30.051.000 ` and `/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11: symbolic link to libodbcci.so.11.30.051.000 `further  . . .  `-rwxr-x--- 1 psql pvsw 662429 jun  5 15:51 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11.30.051.000` and `/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11.30.051.000: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped `

Comment: i'v added some vars to /etc/apache2/envvars  , now it's running under the browser , but not as cronjob (user www-data)

Comment: cronjob also works now . . . i put everything in a shellscript and now i works

Answer (score 0):

Solution, as revealed in comments --

Set the environment variables for each user and process that needs to perform the task, to match the environment that was active for PHP and the psql user.

This was achieved by using a shellscript for the full task.

Comment: Hi there, I'm facing a similar problem. But, I'm not sure what those environment variables should be? Would you be able to help me out with this?

Comment: @CheekuJee The most likely variables set by the original questioner would be `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `ODBCINI`, and `ODBCINSTINI`. There are many other possibilities. You should ask your own question, if this doesn't resolve your issue.